# Html link not registering on some clicks

Tags: javascript, css, events, dom-events

I tried to create a fancy button. Problem that when it is clicked just between text and bottom edge of the button `click` event do not fire. Here is [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iSUmUSAS/3/).

Seems to be that problem in this code:

```
.button:active {
  top:2px;
  box-shadow:0 2px #36c
}
```

But I need this "push" effect. So how to save the effect and get click event back?

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `box-shadow`, use `border-bottom`, like so:

```
.button {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
}

.button:active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/IGUReWO/1/

Comment: Can also change `top:2px` inside the `.button:active` to `margin-top:2px` to get the content below the button to not shift when clicked down

Comment: @SombreErmine, I wasn't sure if he wanted that affect or not but you're right.

Comment: I gotcha. I just figured since his/her jsbin works that way, I would mention how to get it working the same way with this technique. :)

Answer (score 0):

that's because the click event fires on mouseup where as mousedown obviously gets fired on mousedown.
I only could reproduce the behaviour you described, if i click the button and release the mouse outside of it.

If you want the push effect, you could attach the mousedown event instead of the click event and delay it for a few ms, for instance:

```
$('.button').on('mousedown', function() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    var val = parseInt($('.mousedown span').html(), 10);
    val++;
    $('.mousedown span').text(val);
    return false;
  }, 200);
});
```

I hope i could help,
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
box-shadow: 0 4px black;
```

with

```
border-bottom: 4px solid black;
```

and

```
box-shadow:0 2px black;
```

with

```
border-bottom: 2px solid black;
```

You can't click on a box shadow, but you can click on a border.